# Squashed Git merge resulted in desynchronized branches

Tags: git, github

I am in a bit of a situation regarding my dev branch having a different history than my master, despite both of them containing the same content due to a squashed merge.

On Github, I used the "squash and merge" option on my pull request from my `dev` branch to `master`. This has resulted in a separation between `master` and `dev` that doesn't actually exist. According to Github, my `dev` branch is a number of commits ahead of `master` despite those commits being squash-merged into `master`.

Furthermore, the various merges I've done onto `master` from `dev` do not exist on `dev` and thus `dev` is also *behind* `master`. Including a commit that exists on `master` that I have not merged onto `dev` because I know that will only make things worse.

[image: dev compared to master]

How do I resolve this issue? Ideally, since both branches are in fact the same (except 1 commit on `master` that should be ahead of `dev`) how do I synchronize these branches?

I can update my question with more information if more is needed to help understand my tree.

UPDATE:
I have found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039111/github-thinks-branches-are-different-after-merge) and I believe it is indeed the squash that has caused this confusion. I am afraid I will have to revert the merge and perform it again without squashing so that Github can correctly understand the history of the two branches.

I could alternatively squash the commits on the `dev` branch itself and re-merge just the one commit, as I would prefer, but that sacrifices the history of the branch. I think I need to decide between one of these two approaches. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

> I could alternatively squash the commits on the `dev` branch itself and re-merge just the one commit, as I would prefer.

If you do a PR from the pushed `dev` branch to `master`, and merge-squash it... then your local `dev` should effectively be reset to the new `master` state.

```
git fetch
git branch old-dev dev
git checkout -B dev origin/master
```

You can then go on from the new `dev` branch

Comment: Indeed, I suspect the best option might be to discard the current dev branch's history and work from the squashed history.
That's where my problem lies, I think - I hoped that Git/Github would recognise the 1 merge commit on `master` as a collection of commits on `dev` but instead they are considered completely separate, unrelated commits, creating this divergence in history.

Comment: @Psymøn Yes. I have kept the old dev history in a local branch "old-dev", if you need it.